# mongodb sort and searching by _id does not return all items

Tags: python, mongodb, sorting, find, limit

I have a collection with 12 millions of documents that I need to process in python. To speed up my process I'm using multiprocessing. Each process should analyse a subset of documents. To do this I'm using the find and sort by "_id". The first time I limit my search. Example:

`db.Mycollection.find().sort({"_id":1}).limit(1000)`

Then from this query I get the last _id to be used in the following search:

`db.Mycollection.find({"_id":{$gt:last_id}}).sort({"_id":1}).limit(1000)`

until here, everything works fine, but after the process has read about 800000 documents, it does not return any more documents. I get the last_id obtained and executed the search in mongodb console and it does not return any other items, but there are more than 11 millions of documents that I haven't analysed, yet. Why is this happening?

Comment: On first sight it seems the right way to tackle this.
The thing your could do is print the last_ids, and open something like "mongochef" (insert your fav editor) and set the page size to 1000 and check if the last_id's from your code match the stuff in your editor. Maybe you can spot the issue there

Comment: Hi, thanks, for the suggestion. I found out it was one error on my code. It wasn't ordering properly.